# SQL for simple recommender system

Tags: sql

Each record in the **movies** table has:

**user** - user id
**movie** - movie id
**rating** - user rating for the movie

User **1** wants to receive recommendations (list of movies) from the group of users **2,3,4,5,6,7**.
The recommended movies should NOT be found among the movies of user 1 and should have an average rating in the group not less than **3**. At the same time, the movies that were watched by less than 3 people from the group can not be recommended.

Here's my option, but it does not reflect the last requirement:

```
SELECT t2.movie
FROM movies t1 INNER JOIN movies t2
     ON t1.user = 1
     AND t2.user IN(2,3,4,5,6,7)
     AND t2.movie NOT IN ( SELECT movie
                           FROM movies
                           WHERE user = 1 )
GROUP BY(t2.movie)
HAVING AVG(t2.rating)>=3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this not work?

```
SELECT t2.movie
FROM movies t1 INNER JOIN movies t2
     ON t1.user = 1
     AND t2.user IN(2,3,4,5,6,7)
     AND t2.movie NOT IN ( SELECT movie
                           FROM movies
                           WHERE user = 1 )
GROUP BY(t2.movie)
HAVING AVG(t2.rating)>=3 
AND  COUNT(DISTINCT t2.user) >= 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, my mistake was - I tried to add the same "COUNT(DISTINCT t2.user) >= 3" but before grouping.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.movie
FROM movies t1 INNER JOIN movies t2
    ON t1.user = 1
       AND t2.user IN(2,3,4,5,6,7)
       AND t2.movie NOT IN ( SELECT movie
                             FROM movies
                            WHERE user = 1 )
WHERE (select count(distinct t3.user) from movies t3 
         where t3.movie = t2.movie) >= 3
GROUP BY(t2.movie)
HAVING AVG(t2.rating)>=3
```